# Css and html integrating 8 images and logo in the middle

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I already have a piece of css/html code which display 4 images, 2 per row, 2 rows, and logo in the middle of them all.
Now I need to add another set of 4 images right below the first 4 in the same format, with the same logo in the middle
Each image has some text added and a link in it, visible when hoovering over the image.
I've been trying to have it done but can't make it. Was wondering if you're willing to help me out.
My code is here
jsfiddle.net/Cristian_C/b9961995/1/

Thank you

I have no idea how to add the code for a link here

Comment: Please provide some code. Show us some work you did.

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to SO. Please have a look here to improve your question(s): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 Really sorry, I have now added a fiddle instead of live link. The fiddle will remain online indefinitely.

Comment: Your [mcve] need to exist *in your question*, not on another site

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you're mixing inline styles with stylesheets, but you should (as a rule) avoid it, as it will make maintaining your CSS a nightmare (separation also makes the DOM more readable for you, too).

Because of the code bloat, I'm not sure if you have important styles in there that are essential to your markup; however, there's an easy way to achieve what you want to do by utilizing `z-index`, `float` and `clear`.

See my [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nkm9yyb/).

Comment: Thank you for the help. It looks great on fiddle but when I add it to my server it shows 2 rows with 4 images each, and the "logo" is over the last image in the row.
Unfortunately I need the code in the fiddle because there is a layer over each image along with some text and link which appear when you hoover over each image.